# Concept for sql groupby statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Below query says, find the number of shippers from order table with shipper info as well as employee info.

```
   select Count(Shipper.ShipperID),Shipper.ShipperName from [Order] 
left join Shipper
on
[Order].ShipperID =  Shipper.ShipperID
group by ShipperID
```

Above query gives Error on groupby ShipperID. When i change it to ShipperName, it works fine.
Error i get is: Ambiguous column name 'ShipperID'.

I need to understand why this happens so? I cannot understand on w3schools or any other site.

Comment: both table [order] and [shipper] contain the field 'shipperID'  the error is simply stating which table do you want to group by (Probably [shipper].[shipperID] as [order].[shipperID] could be null.  However that will will not fix the problem.   Every field in the select that is not part of an aggregate (count, max sum, min as examples) MUST be in teh group by if an aggregate is present in SQL server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to count the orders for each shipper then I recommend that you do something like this

```
Select s.ShipperID, s.ShipperName,
       (Select Count(1) From [Order] as o where o.ShipperId = s.ShipperId) as OrderCount
from Shipper as s
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select Count(Shipper.ShipperID),Shipper.ShipperName from [Order] 
left join Shipper
on [Order].ShipperID =  Shipper.ShipperID
group by Shipper.ShipperName
```

When you add any Aggregate function in sql server's select statement, Sql server knows it needs to do that aggregate operation on all the rows returned from that query.

Now when you add another column name in your select query and it is not contained in any aggregate function, Just the column name on it own. Now Sql server needs to know what to do with this Column when rows are returned.

An aggregate function own its own is simple are straight forward sql server will simply perform that operation on all the values returned from that query in each row and returns a single row with a scalar value.

But when you have another column name in your select statement that is not contained in an aggregate function, This will return multiple rows for this column, Now If sql server shows SUM of first column and all the rows from 2nd column this will show inaccurate results. There sql server throw and error and you will need to GROUP the results retuned by your aggregate function by the column that is not contained in any aggregate function.

*Your Query*

If you only SELECT the count of ShipperID it will return an integer showing the count of ShipperIDs let say 10, Now when you add ShipperName in your select statement, The results will shows something like 10 for count column and all the ShipperName in your second column, and you will end up with a result set something like 10, 10 , 10 in front of each shipperName, which will be a wrong count and obviously sql server will not execute this statement.

But if you add GROUP BY ShipperName in your select statement, The Count will No Longer Show 10 for each ShipperName but The COUNT for each ShipperName something like 1, 3,4,2 and so on.....
I hope this will help you to understand. :)

Comment: Yes but Why it gives error on group by ShipperID ??

Answer (score 0):

Try giving a alias and group by `ShipperName` : since it is not included in aggregated clause

```
select Count(S.ShipperID),S.ShipperName from Order O 
left join Shipper S
on
O.ShipperID =  S.ShipperID
group by S.ShipperName
```

Answer (score 0):

The ambiguous error is due to the fact that you have ShipperId in both the tables. If you were to change it to Shipper.ShipperId you would end up with an error stating that Shipper.ShipperName is not contained in an aggregate function and I dont see the need for you to do a count() and a group by on the same column. If you are interested in getting just one row per Shipper id then you should probably do something like this.

> select Count(distinct Shipper.ShipperID),Shipper.ShipperName from [Order] 
>   left join Shipper
>   on [Order].ShipperID =  Shipper.ShipperID
>   group by Shipper.ShipperName